# Does $f^{-1}[C] = f^{-1} [D]\implies C=D$?

Tags: functions, discrete-mathematics

I just study about "Image and Inverse Image of the function".

So I decide to prove by myself, is it correct?
[image]

Thank you :D

Comment: If one of the answers below answered your question, the way this site works works, you'd "accept" the answer, more here: [What should I do when someone answers my question?](https://stackoverflow.com/help/someone-answers). But only if your question really has been answered. If not, consider adding more details to the question.

Answer (score 1):

The problem is that if you do the inverse image of two sets C and D and they give you the same result, that only means that every value that doesn't give you the empty set as its inverse image, or equivalently, every value that belongs to im(f), is in both C and D. But the other ones, the ones that give you the empty set as inverse image, or equivalently the ones that doesn't belong to im(f), they can be different. Drawing pictures always helps.
In your proof you say that there are two cases, but if you have the equality beforehand, why do you need to consider those two cases?
Furthermore, it is true that for every f(x) in C you have f(x) in D too, and viceversa, but the problem is the same: there could be elements in C or D that don't come from any x, so you can't write them as f(x), but they are still in the set.

Answer (score 0):

That's not true.
Let $f(x) = \cos(x)$.
Then $f^{-1}(\Bbb R) = f^{-1}([-1,1])$.

---

The thing with your proof is that your conclusion at $(1)$ is incorrect.
We'd have $x \in f^{-1}(C) \implies x \in f^{-1}(D) \implies f(x) \in D$.
In other words:

$$\forall x \in f^{-1}(C),\, f(x) \in D.$$

Similarly, for number $(2)$ we'd have

$$\forall x \in f^{-1}(D),\, f(x) \in C.$$

So what you can say is that $\forall x \in f^{-1}(C), \, f(x) \in C\cap D$.

However, you need statements like $\forall x \in C, \, x \in D$ and vice versa.
You can't get these statements from $(1)$ and $(2)$.

Comment: Why f^-1[R] equals to f^-1[[0,2pi)]??
there's an x that makes cos(x) = 2pi???

Comment: Clearly I was not very well when I wrote the answer. It should be fixed.